# Error deploying java application to weblogic

Tags: java, wsdl, weblogic-10.x

I'm trying to deploy an application I have to look into to weblogic 10.3.6.0. Nad I get the following error:

```
weblogic.wsee.jaxws.framework.policy.advertisementimpl.AdvertisementHelperImpl registerExtension
WARNING: Registering oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.addressing.AddressingExtensionRegistry extension failed; java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.j2ee.ws.wsdl.extensions.addressing.AddressingExtensionRegistry
weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate addWsdlDefinitionFeature
SEVERE: Failed to create WsdlDefinitionFeature for wsdl location: http://localhost:7001/banking-integration-test/ws?wsdl, error: com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException, message: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.
```

Wsdl does exist at the exact path. What might be the problem? What is missing class AddressingExtensionRegistry? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: How do you deploy your application? WAR? Please make sure the file contains the oracle driver (JAR).

Comment: Looks like your application has webservice binding and Weblogic think that its incorrect - cannot find wsdl location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AddressingExtensionRegistry` lives in `com.oracle.ws.orawsdl_x.x.x.jar` if this is not in your common modules it can be placed in the lib folder of your domain.

If your web service requires authentication you will need to add `com.oracle.ws.http_client_1.2.0.0.jar` as well to avoid `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HTTPClient/AuthorizationPrompter`.

In both cases make sure that you don't have duplicates in your common modules and lib folders as this can cause problems.